# GLView won't show up in React Native? But no errors?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, three.js, expo, webgl

Im trying to get a basic three.js scene to display in my RN app. Ive followed https://github.com/expo/expo-three example verbatim, however the snack provided is out of date and Im lost here. I've imported everything correctly and have no errors in console - but nothing displays.

Working in a functional component, I have:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  // Clear the animation loop when the component unmounts
  return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
}, []);

<GLView
                                style={{ flex: 1, zIndex: 6, width: wp('100%'), height: hp('50%') }}
                                onContextCreate={async (gl: ExpoWebGLRenderingContext) => {
                                  const { drawingBufferWidth: width, drawingBufferHeight: height } = gl;
                                  const sceneColor = 0x6ad6f0;
                                  console.log('hello world');

                                  // Create a WebGLRenderer without a DOM element
                                  const renderer = new Renderer({ gl });
                                  renderer.setSize(width, height);
                                  renderer.setClearColor(sceneColor);

                                  const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(70, width / height, 0.01, 1000);
                                  camera.position.set(2, 5, 5);

                                  const scene = new Scene();
                                  scene.fog = new Fog(sceneColor, 1, 10000);
                                  scene.add(new GridHelper(10, 10));

                                  const ambientLight = new AmbientLight(0x101010);
                                  scene.add(ambientLight);

                                  const pointLight = new PointLight(0xffffff, 2, 1000, 1);
                                  pointLight.position.set(0, 200, 200);
                                  scene.add(pointLight);

                                  const spotLight = new SpotLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
                                  spotLight.position.set(0, 500, 100);
                                  spotLight.lookAt(scene.position);
                                  scene.add(spotLight);

                                  const cube = new BoxBufferGeometry(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                                  scene.add(cube);

                                  camera.lookAt(cube.position);

                                  function update() {
                                    cube.rotation.y += 0.05;
                                    cube.rotation.x += 0.025;
                                  }

                                  // Setup an animation loop
                                  const render = () => {
                                    timeout = requestAnimationFrame(render);
                                    update();
                                    renderer.render(scene, camera);
                                    gl.endFrameEXP();
                                  };

                                  render();
                                }}
                              />
```

I know that the `onContextCreate()` isnt being called because no 'hello world' is printed to console. Does three.js not work in React native anymore? What is wrong here and where can I find a working example?

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but did you mean to use `new Renderer({ gl });` rather than `new WebGLRenderer({ context: gl });`? Or are you using a three.js wrapper that maps `WebGLRenderer` -> `Renderer`? (I may be way off-base from the actual problem--my React Native experience is extremely limited.)

Comment: @TheJim01 nope .. neither show anything